# How do I stop Alexa from including the application owner's name

Tags: alexa, amazon-echo

Yesterday I installed the Alexa app on my wife's phone so that she can control the Echo from it.

Her Amazon account is linked to mine so I logged into the app with her account.

However, ever since, whenever we trigger an application Alexa now replies with "XXX's App" instead of just the app name.

It's not a major thing but it's a little bit annoying!

Is there any way to revert this back?

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess; but I would try using the exact same Amazon account to log into the app on all of your phones. This is how my girlfriend and I have it set, and it doesn't add our names to the apps. It does still know about both of us, though, and has both of our phones in there for caller ID etc.